# Typescript mixin fails when trying to use base class method

Tags: typescript, mixins

[MCVE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQ1-gUCAEDKBLAtgBwDYFMYGM0EMBnAmACzwDcEA7AcxjxiQwBcSB7AE0l0OIFUCGAE4wA3jBiQJBPAE8AEhjRo2ACiQEaALgLMh1GgEpRUiWexsqBNpgB0Kmus2HTAX0jvYAOQwYOfmAAzNhE8ZUYEAA9qAkhmWRQsAGFLXSEAV2xmEIAeABUYAF4xVwA+IpgqDAB3GFVbBrwhGgIteipZAG0AXUMi8ryAbmgIUYgRmABBCOiqGFY8ZnoODmIGJlZOebIl9ME1mAAjQiweIkYWdi5A9KoshEsp+-JFvEPMfIAhE5gMSOYMFRVjAUlY9JlskJSqpvoI2nlYRg+iYJEIWOkhHMzsQ-gCgcREWIzJJiXhnosMKpkcSJKZiTCfoQYLcANZUNjVOZMgTCQy2GQKJQqVQAIjJzAQLwBHBFLmJ7gkrmGnjGqpAEwEBm2pzYqDYgg4OHwRBGarG3FSS0m5PeGB5ImK1olUremFU9pcFjB9BtmHtFSqtSdktddsEQipkHFIdt9ts0allMMQA)

I would like to create a mixin, that can use a mehod of the class into which it was mixed. However this is not working.

```js
////////////////////
// Simple class
class User {  
  sayHello(msg:string){
      console.log(msg)
  }
}
// Needed for all mixins
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
////////////////////
// A mixin that adds a method that uses a base class method
function Activatable<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {    
    activate() {      
      (Base as unknown as User).sayHello("activated")
    }
  };
}
////////////////////
// Using the composed class
////////////////////
const ActivableUser = Activatable(User)
const activableUser = new ActivableUser()
activableUser.activate()
```

Run fails with `[ERR]: Base.sayHello is not a function` .

Is there any way I can create a mixin that has access to base class methods and properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Base` in the `activate` method is the class constructor. It is *not* an instance. And `activate` is an method on instances.

But since `activate` is an instance method, you can just use `this` instead.

Just replace `Base` with `this` and it works just fine.

```
function Activatable<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {    
    activate() {      
      (this as unknown as User).sayHello("activated")
    }
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/PQ1-gsAUCAEBlAlgWwA4BsCmcDGGBDAZyJn2KLgFUisAnOAbzjhhaIIE8AJLDDAPYAKFEQDmALiIAXOkgB2YgJSM2LdbgHyiA7ADpBYkeKVqAvjAuxgcAHJYsAEydwAZgIYF+cFEgAeCqTQ0pxoOADCWjJ0AK640h4APAAqcAC8TGYAfOlw8lgA7nBCeqUEdGJEEnAE8pwA2gC6Suk5yQDcMBDd3V02AII+-gpw0gAWBNI1jo6UBD5Y4wKOoxNTMbRzcABGxDjkJAtLjjCuMfLxSFpw-ZcAbpME29gpAEJ7cFh+0ljys3CRbSyOIJOhZITvWjVZKQrAtVTQFh0RYxOjyPCEQ5fH5-SiwpjqViI9QEe6TLBCeGElhqQlCcZIOaUc4Aa3kAgK6OI1FodCUeg4PD4giEACJSdIkA8fo5RaZiSwrIrOtArD11aA+jyFGJVvsBOgBLQVgcghqNWQolNbpKHs8sDR6LkbVLHvahI6+ZagTUyfbPbl8kUXXbsJ7Kd6dPpDPTQlgBK5fbanmHeXoJa6fvKM6GHWmc+TKUA)

---

Additionally, you can get rid of that nasty cast through `unknown` if you tell the mixin what instance methods it depends on.

```
function Activatable<
  TBase extends Constructor<{ sayHello(msg: string): void }>
>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {    
    activate() {      
      this.sayHello("activated")
    }
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/PQ1-gsAUCAEBlAlgWwA4BsCmcDGGBDAZyJn2KLgFUisAnOAbzjhhaIIE8AJLDDAPYAKFEQDmALiIAXOkgB2YgJSM2LdbgHyiA7ADpBYkeKVqAvjAuxgcAHJYsAEydwAZgIYF+cFEgAeCqTQ0pxoOADCWjJ0AK640h4APAAqcAC8TGYAfOlw8lgA7nBCeqUEdGJEEnAE8pwA2gC6Suk5yQDcMDAQPT3dNgCCPv4KcNIAFgTSNY6OlAQ+WBMCjmOT0zG083AARsQ45CSLy44wrjHy8UhacANXAG5TBDvYKQBC+3BYftJY8nNwSLaWRxBJ0RLMDg8PiCYySODRBTKar3ARIVbZLJCD60arJHFYFqqaAsOhLGJ0eR4QhHb6-f6UAlMdSsEnqAgPKZYIRElksNQsiZIIh6KG8fjCABEHOkSEev0cktMbJYVlVnWgVl62tA-WoRCRawOAnQAloq0OQR1OrIUWmd1ljxeWBo9FyDrlT2dQlddGVmmBNU5zt9uXyRQ9Tuwvp5tu0uiwBgERhCYQEriDjue0dodD0Ms9v2VBajLtz+c5vx5QA)

Comment: I wonder if I could use an interface with many methods instead of manually writing `Constructor<{ sayHello(msg: string): void }`, so if I have an interface `CanSayHello` with method `sayHello` ( and other methods ), how do I work this into this constructor definition? ( supposing `User` is defined as a class implementing this interface )

Comment: You can put any object like type in `Constructor<WhateverTypeHere>`. You could put an interface that has that method. Or you could even [put a class in there](https://tsplay.dev/N9pE1w). Or you could make a type alias like `type UserMaker = Constructer<User>` if you want to be really short about it.

Answer (score 1):

Fot completeness, based on @Alex Wayne's answer and his additional guidence in the comment, here is the solution I was really aiming for, namely to constrain the base class with an interface that it has to implement and require this interface from the base class in the mixin function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQ1-gsAUCAEBJAdgFwKYCcBmBDAxmnCgBY4pwD2ArhnAEY4DOheANk43KZyhXAJYBbAA6s0gtKhj9UmXATgBhHEgDKOAJ4AJNK1Z8A3jDhxGmnXooAKQYwDmALkYoMMuwEoHANwr8AJjAAvjAwEGFhocBwAEJMLOyMjDBsHHAAqsy0QqLikiicymrmuvpwBibGpsWWNvZOLm7uRtAmrXB4FEiMFGIAdPp2tR6VwdCjkeGTwJFwAHJoaH6LcFgUtDh6cIL8AB4ySdAoGsKEip3OGFR4vBgAPAAqcAC8ZYEAfM9wSGgA7nBWvUBOAwdkYDjgKg0AG0ALruZ4fe4AbhCsCmkxmAEEtrsZERSOQcH4-JwcFs0CQKH58WQ4FRmKT6HF2glOBJKQFoFgqEhrvxOnBMXyvGQcHQxA9Ysw4GgdugkCSlOcXFcbrdCuptCUKG83lYpWhwfcDfDmiYMBSaEgWalZfLFQaym1KiZ8Ch+CL0FZTW0Ki1fSR+IxemYtTUAERuj1kRbh9wuuCjEyBFFjVHojFopQWshufEsCgiCjMakpRLJZWC4VisQZTCfIXuz01tBWOsYePQDpdQnV8Vodufb5-RvR-vt73pjMRLMZPMkAtFks28vQKMi8eZXrrmPeoA)

```js
////////////////////
// Interface that our base class has to implement
interface CanSayHello {
  sayHello(msg:string):void
}

////////////////////
// Base class
class User implements CanSayHello {  
  sayHello(msg:string){
      console.log(msg)
  }
}

////////////////////
// Needed for all mixins
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

////////////////////
// A mixin that adds a method that uses a base class method
function Activatable<TBase extends Constructor<CanSayHello>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {    
    activate() {      
      this.sayHello("activated")
    }
  };
}

////////////////////
// Creating the composed class
const ActivableUser = Activatable(User)
const activableUser = new ActivableUser()

////////////////////
// Using the composed class
activableUser.activate()
```